# Lampp (xampp) stop after reboot, not work autostart on Ubuntu

Tags: server, php, lamp, autostart, xampp

I am working with Ubuntu Server 15.04, I have a problem at some point in the night the computer restarts or shuts off the power goes out or simply stops working the lampp (Xampp) apachefriends, I tried to fix it with command lines:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp /etc/init.d/lampp
sudo update-rc.d lampp start 80 2 3 4 5 . stop 30 0 1 6 .
```

The first line works correctly, the second gives me the following errors:

```
administrador@ServPRO:~$ sudo update-rc.d lampp start 80 2 3 4 5 . stop 30 0 1 6 .
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-rc.d: warning: start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match lampp Default-Start values (3 5)
update-rc.d: warning: stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match lampp Default-Stop values (0 1 2 6)
```

reboot:

```
administrador@ServPRO:~$ last -x | grep reboot
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Wed Jun 15 09:15 - 09:32  (00:16)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Wed Jun 15 06:13 - 09:12  (02:59)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Wed Jun 15 05:40 - 09:12  (03:32)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Wed Jun  8 09:24 - 09:12 (6+23:48)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Wed Jun  8 05:51 - 09:12 (7+03:21)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Mon Jun  6 06:44 - 09:12 (9+02:28)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Sun Jun  5 05:43 - 09:12 (10+03:29)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Wed Jun  1 06:50 - 09:12 (14+02:21)
reboot   system boot  3.19.0-15-generi Wed Jun  1 06:07 - 09:12 (14+03:05)
```

I'm new and not to do research on google, fails to find something related to ubuntu server 15.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
From upgrading si Operation sistem... from 15.04 version to 15.10 version stable of ubuntu... it overwrite all services os i have modified and up alll services pre required form software added... one of it is Lampp from Xamp stack...

Comment: While we appreciate that you try to answer your own question this post is in no way clear - do you intend to tell us your issue "solved itself"?

Comment: is clearly explained that the problem was solved, at what point ?: RESP: after making the upgrade of S.O.